# Creating a DVD-player compatible movie file

Tags: video, encoding, codec, mpeg4

I've created encoded a MPEG-4 file with mplayer and placed it on a DVD. The file is identified as

> RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 320 x 240, 25.00 fps, video: FFMpeg MPEG-4, audio: uncompressed PCM (stereo, 96000 Hz)

I've tried playing it on a [Samsung 1080p DVD player](http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/tv-video/dvd-players/dvd-players/DVD-1080P9/XAA/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail) and the codecs were not recognised. There are no firmware upgrades available for my region (Romania).

How should I pick the codecs to make sure that the files are readable by this DVD player?

---

*Update*: The command line I used is similar to

```
mencoder -dvd 2 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vpass=1 -oac copy -o movie.avi
mencoder -dvd 2 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vpass=2 -oac copy -o movie.avi
```

Comment: Do you know what command line you used to encode with MEncoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Samsung 1080p DVD Player does not support h.264 MP4, only DivX/XviD codecs.

I recommend you try these settings :

```
Video Codec : DivX/XviD (either one will do)
Frame Rate : 25 or 29.7 (25 for better file size)
Video Size : Max 640 width (for height go with the aspect ratio of your video)
Audio Codec : MP3 128kbps Stereo VBR
```

It should play now - I recommend you use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to encode.